# Генерация строки из комбинации указаных символов (Brute Force) - C#

Tags: c#

Требуется генерировать (не рандомно) строку из комбинации переданных символов.

```
//symbols = [A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+[. , / _] 

public IEnumerable<string> GenerateString (ArrayList symbols, int LengthOfString)
{
    // Генерация строки

    // Фильтр (если один и тот же символ "последовательно" повторяется
    // больше 2-х раз, то строка не валидна и переходить к генерации следующей строки)

    yield return GeneratedString;
}
```

Пример:

```
// symbols = [abcde];
foreach (var string in GenerateString (symbols, 3))
{
    // Запись в текстовом файле
}
```

вывод

> abc,bac,cab,bca,abd,dac.... ade,dea,dca....

и так далее.
примечание
ааb,aaa - чтобы не генерировался

Comment: GenerateString() у Вас должен генерировать одну строку или список? Почему GenerateString возвращает IEnumerable<string> ?

Comment: Я хотел использовать именно {yield return} не хочу нигде хранить принцип Генерировать>Пользоваться>Забыть в цикле foreach при каждом обращении возвращать только одну сгенерированную строку (очень удобно если дальше использовать параллельность)

Comment: ..... // больше 2-х раз,.... и в то же время "ааb,aaa - чтобы не генерировался" ну допустим aaa подпадает под критерий "больше 2-х раз", но aab нет. Уточните, подряд идущих повторений вообще быть не может или же дубль допустим?

Comment: Как раз  aab = плохо   aba = хорошо

Comment: Если говорить программным языком то (..... // больше 2-х раз, или равно)

Comment: Гдето на просторах www.github.com нашол, но пример не работает, Visual Studio 2015 ругается на код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetAllMatches(char[] chars, int length)
{
    int[] indexes = new int[length];
    char[] current = new char[length];
    for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        current[i] = chars[0];
    }
    do
        {
            yield return new string(current);
        }
        while (Increment(indexes, current, chars));
}

private static bool Increment(int[] indexes, char[] current, char[] chars)
{
    int position = indexes.Length-1;

    while (position >= 0)
    {
        indexes[position]++;
        if (indexes[position] < chars.Length)
        {
             current[position] = chars[indexes[position]];
             return true;
        }
        indexes[position] = 0;
        current[position] = chars[0];
        position--;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228796/algorithm-odometer-brute-force

Comment: нужно было просто выделить текст и нажать кнопку `{}`